# Angular 4 `ng build-prod` failed with an error that makes no sense

Tags: angular, webpack

Is there a way, to find out what it causing it to fail?

`ng build` and `ng build -prod --aot=false` works however `ng build -prod` doesn't work. Not sure why?

[image]

Here is `ng -v` if that helps

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.1
@angular/common: 4.3.1
@angular/compiler: 4.3.1
@angular/core: 4.3.1
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/forms: 4.3.1
@angular/http: 4.3.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.1
@angular/router: 4.3.1
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.1
@angular/language-service: 4.3.1
```

UPDATE:
After updating the CLI and Packages in package.json I am getting a new error:
[image]

here is the new set of version:

```
@angular/cli: 1.3.0
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.4
@angular/common: 4.3.4
@angular/compiler: 4.3.4
@angular/core: 4.3.4
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-rc.1
@angular/forms: 4.3.4
@angular/http: 4.3.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.4
@angular/router: 4.3.4
@angular/cli: 1.3.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.4
@angular/language-service: 4.3.4
```

Now I am not even able to `ng serve`

Comment: Did you install node_modules using yarn by any chance?

Comment: nope. Shall I try to remove modules and re-add it using `npm install` ?

Comment: It's always worth a shot.

Comment: @KirkLarkin No luck

Comment: In order for someone more knowledgeable to help, I suggest you list your @angular/cli version, your node.js version, your npm version and your typescript version.

Comment: @User1911 When reinstalling, you are supposed to install @angular/cli and then the rest of your modules.

Comment: @Ploppy Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ploppy I have updated my cli and packages and I am having a new error. I have updated my question.

Comment: You are supposed to install in 2 steps: First the CLI, then the rest of the modules. So in order to do a clean install, remove your `node_modules` folder, then `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli` then `npm install`. It may not be related but I think it's worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely angularcli compatiblity issue. First update your angularcli in ur environment and update package.json file to latest. It will get resolved. I fixed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to update the dependencies manually, which may result in some version incompatibilities. This is how I upgraded my projects to Angular CLI 1.3.0:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g

npm install @angular/cli -g

ng new hello-world
```

After that, delete node_modules from your project and copy the dependencies and devDependencies sections from package.json of the newly generated project replacing these sections in your project's package.json.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the error `can't resolve ngfactory` is related to `enhanced-resolve` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7113